# Touchpad scroll is slow in VMware for ThinkPad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, vmware, thinkpad

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on VMWare 12.1, I have a Lenovo Thinkpad. The toucpad two finger scrolling in Windows is smooth and it accelerates when I move my fingers, it is also good when I use in an standard installation of ubuntu beside Windows, but in WMWare scrolling is slow. for example in **firefox**, it seems you must pull the scroll bar slowly and it stops as you leave your fingers (it doesn't accelerate)

**Update**: in mouse settings in Ubuntu under VMware there is no touchpad section.

Should I install some drivers for linux under VMware, or I must install driver for VMware or maybe VMWare itself send touch pad messages to the linux? because touchpad works but is slow.

Comment: Do you have 16.04.1? that should fix it, by running unity in some low graphics mode

Comment: @Daniel as I noticed Touchpad is not installed on the linux under VMWare

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer for my question:

https://superuser.com/questions/131297/use-synaptics-touchpad-scroll-in-vmware-guest

according to it, I used the instruction in this article http://blog.alexou.net/scrolling-in-gtk-apps-with-synaptics-driver to add a DWORD to my touchpad driver on windows, and now it was fixed!